# How to insert values to DB without force the user fill all the form without get any error of undefind index

Tags: php, html, pdo

I have a form with several inputs and select and option, when user selects a value in the select and option (yes or no), opens with jQuery the fields that is need to fill so we get a situation that the user don't fill all the form 
only what he need, and some inputs stay empty but I get undefined index error on the fields that stay empty.

The question is how to avoid this error.

I don't now what I should have tried

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $platform =  json_encode($_POST['platform']);
    $advertising_history = $_POST['advertising_history'];
    $advertising_external = $_POST['advertising_external'];
    $period_of_time_office = $_POST['period_of_time_office'];
    $price_satisfaction_office = $_POST['price_satisfaction_office'];
    $service_satisfaction_office = $_POST['service_satisfaction_office'];
    $effectiveness_advertising_office = 
    $_POST['effectiveness_advertising_office'];
    $advertising_price_range = $_POST['advertising_price_range'];
    $effectiveness_advertising = $_POST['effectiveness_advertising'];
    $outweb_advertising = $_POST['outweb_advertising'];
    $outweb_location = $_POST['outweb_location'];
    $outweb_effectiveness = $_POST['outweb_effectiveness'];

    $valid = true;

    if ($valid) {
        try {
            $pdo = DB();
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO client_form_5(
                        client_id,
                        advertising_history,
                        advertising_external,
                        period_of_time_office,
                        price_satisfaction_office,
                        service_satisfaction_office,
                        effectiveness_advertising_office,
                        platform,
                        advertising_price_range,
                        effectiveness_advertising,
                        outweb_advertising,
                        outweb_location,
                        outweb_effectiveness
                    )
                VALUES (
                        :client_id,
                        :advertising_history,
                        :advertising_external,
                        :period_of_time_office,
                        :price_satisfaction_office,
                        :service_satisfaction_office,
                        :effectiveness_advertising_office,
                        :platform,
                        :advertising_price_range,
                        :effectiveness_advertising,
                        :outweb_advertising,
                        :outweb_location,
                        :outweb_effectiveness
                  )");

              $stmt->bindParam("client_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
              $stmt->bindParam("advertising_history", $advertising_history, 
              PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt->bindParam("advertising_external", $advertising_external, 
              PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt->bindParam("period_of_time_office", $period_of_time_office, 
              PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt->bindParam("price_satisfaction_office", $price_satisfaction_office, 
              PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt->bindParam("service_satisfaction_office", 
              $service_satisfaction_office, PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt->bindParam("effectiveness_advertising_office", 
              $effectiveness_advertising_office, PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt->bindParam("platform", $platform, PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt->bindParam("advertising_price_range", $advertising_price_range, 
              PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt->bindParam("effectiveness_advertising", $effectiveness_advertising, 
              PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt->bindParam("outweb_advertising", $outweb_advertising, 
              PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt->bindParam("outweb_location", $outweb_location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt->bindParam("outweb_effectiveness", $outweb_effectiveness, 
              PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if an element of `$_POST` exists.

You can use ternary expression to assign a default value for a missing `$_POST`

In example :

```
$myVar = ((isset($_POST['someFormInput'])) ? ($_POST['someFormInput']) : ("default value")); //default value can be null or whatever
```

This will does the same than :

```
if (isset($_POST['someFormInput']))
{
    $myVar = $_POST['someFormInput'];
}
else
{
    $myVar = "default value";
}
```

Comment: I've been faster :D yay \o/

Comment: Yea :) I had to edit the code so it was vaguely readable first :) :)

Comment: @YosefDadya feel free to accept one of our answers as accepted, if you don't know which one to choose, you can toss a coin

Answer (score 1):

You have to check each input has been set and if not set a default that suites the column type in the table.

So for each, and here is just an example of one field

```
$advertising_history = isset($_POST['advertising_history']) 
                            ? $_POST['advertising_history'] 
                            : '<some_default>';
```